# Rspec force mobile_fu to detect mobile device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mobile-fu

Is there a way to write rspec tests for the mobile version of my application?

I use `mobile_fu` to detect whether the call originates from a mobile device or not.

But now rspec would need to fool `mobile_fu` in believing it's a mobile request...

Comment: What library do you use for acceptance testing?

Comment: I'm using rspec with capybara.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/03/configuring-user-agents-with-capybara-selenium-webdriver/) had the perfect solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use RSpec to drive Webrat, and set Webrat user agent to simulate a mobile device:

http://robert-reiz.com/2012/02/27/integration-tests-with-rspec/

Comment: Can something similar be done with Capybara? Or am I mixing things here that don't belong together?

Comment: Think I found something here: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/03/configuring-user-agents-with-capybara-selenium-webdriver/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go http://blog.sparqcode.com/2011/03/07/custom-user-agent-strings-with-cucumber-and-capybara/

Comment: Have been able to make it work with http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/03/configuring-user-agents-with-capybara-selenium-webdriver/. Looks a little bit more easy than the link you provided.